# $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0 }\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)x^k + f^{(k+1)}(c)(x-x_0)^{k+1}}{g^{(k)}(x_0)x^k + g^{(k+1)}(c)(x-x_0)^{k+1}}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Doing a division $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ of two Taylor polynomials of functions $f$ and $g$ of the form $$f(x) = T_{n,x_0}f(x)+R_{n,x_0}f(x) = \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}x^k + \frac{f^{(k+1)}(c)}{(k+1)!}(x-x_0)^{k+1}$$ with Lagrange remainders $$R_{n,x_0}f(x) = \frac{f^{(k+1)}(c)}{(k+1)}(x-x_0)^{k+1}$$ leads to the following:

$$...=\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)x^k + f^{(k+1)}(c)(x-x_0)^{k+1}}{g^{(k)}(x_0)x^k + g^{(k+1)}(c)(x-x_0)^{k+1}}$$

Is it clear that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0 }\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)x^k + f^{(k+1)}(c)(x-x_0)^{k+1}}{g^{(k)}(x_0)x^k + g^{(k+1)}(c)(x-x_0)^{k+1}} = \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)x^k}{g^{(k)}(x_0)x^k}$$

from this expression alone (since one argues that $(x-x_0)^{k+1} \rightarrow 0$)?

$^{(k)}$ refers to the $k$th derivative.

Comment: Without the context of the original question, it's hard to say for sure, but I believe the $c$ for $f^{(k+1)}$ and $g^{(k+1)}$ need not be the same.

Comment: @Math1000 These are generic Taylor polynomials of the form $f(x) = T_{n,x_0}f(x)+R_{n,x_0}f(x)$ with Lagrange remainders. It's very easy to write the division.

Comment: That is a fairly moot point. But in your proposed expression for the limit, shouldn't the $x^k$ be $x_0^k$? I see an issue there if $x_0=0$.